# ABS 4.3.0 - android.support.v4.app.Watson does not exist

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I did a straight swap of ABS 4.2.0 for 4.3.0 and now I'm getting errors during compilation.

```
java: package android.support.v4.app.Watson does not exist
```

I'm using IntelliJ, both the main project and the ABS library project are using the android-support-v4.jar that was bundled with 4.3.0.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Well, that class is still in the GitHub repo, and it appears in the ZIP file. Have you examined your ActionBarSherlock project to see if the class exists there?

Comment: Yes I can use the IDE to click on ".Watson" and the code is shown as expected. It just seems to be missed at compile time.

Comment: That is really strange. I have no idea how you are picking up the rest of the ABS source and not that particular package's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out the issue, but trashing all the libraries from the project and adding them back in one by one has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ABS 4.3.x is screwed up. It includes an incomplete support.v4 and adding the full support.v4 causes a duplicate which crashes you app. ABS 4.3.x is screwed up.